# global var with session_start();

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created a login form with php and mysql,

this is page that should appear after login:

```
<?php
session_start();
   require_once 'helper.php';

if( ! isset ($_SESSION['user_id'] )){

    header('location: index.php');
}
  ?>

 <?php
include 'header.php';
?>
```

I added this code to  disable access to the page if the user is not logged in.
My problem is that after I added this code I can't log in with user that I could log in with before.
I guess it's because it's can't recognize the global

```
  var $_SESSION['user_id']
```

but I don't understand why, the session_start(); is on the begging of the page.

this is the login page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'helper.php';

$error = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ?
            trim($_POST['email']) : '';
    $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ?
            trim($_POST['password']) : '';

    if (!$email) {
        $error = '*הכנס אימייל';
    } elseif (!$password) {

        $error = '*הכנס סיסמה';
    } else {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
          password = '$password' ";
        $link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['íd'];

            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['name'];

            header('location: posts.php');
        } else {
            $error = 'אימייל או סיסמה לא נכונים';
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php
include("header.php");
?>
<div id="space-signup"></div>
<div class="container">
    <section id="signup">
        <form action="" method="post" style="width:300px; margin:0 auto; ">

            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="אימייל"  value="<?= old('email'); ?>" class="form-control">

            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  
                   placeholder="סיסמה" class="form-control">

            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="sign in"  
                    style="width:300px" >התחבר</button>
            <span class="sign-in-error"> <?= $error ?></span>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161976/discussion-on-question-by-rir-eij-probem-with-global-var-with-session-start).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should replace `$user['íd']`  by `$user['id']` or whatever your column name is.
Please see modified code as below.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'helper.php';

$error = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ?
            trim($_POST['email']) : '';
    $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ?
            trim($_POST['password']) : '';

    if (!$email) {
        $error = '*הכנס אימייל';
    } elseif (!$password) {

        $error = '*הכנס סיסמה';
    } else {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 
          password = '$password' ";
        $link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];

            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['name'];

            header('location: posts.php');
        } else {
            $error = 'אימייל או סיסמה לא נכונים';
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php
include("header.php");
?>
<div id="space-signup"></div>
<div class="container">
    <section id="signup">
        <form action="" method="post" style="width:300px; margin:0 auto; ">

            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="אימייל"  value="<?= old('email'); ?>" class="form-control">

            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  
                   placeholder="סיסמה" class="form-control">

            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="sign in"  
                    style="width:300px" >התחבר</button>
            <span class="sign-in-error"> <?= $error ?></span>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `ob_start()` before starting your session because
If by default your output_buffering is Off and you have been unfortunate enough to send a single byte of data back to the client then your HTTP headers have already been sent. Which effectively prevents session_start() from passing the cookie header back to the client. By calling ob_start() you enable buffering and therefore delay sending http headers.